# I need to override backbone.sync to allow PUT methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

I need to override Backbone.sync to allow **PUT** the problem is i don't know how and where to put it.

This is my Model:

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
var Input = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: 'http://localhost/InterprisePOS/SOP/mobilecreateinvoice/',
initialize: function(){

},
toJSON : function() {
  return _.clone({ input:this.attributes });
},

});
return Input;
});
```

This is my Save function in my view:

```
save: function(){
    invoice = new Invoice();
    input = new Input();
    invoice.set({POSWorkstationID: "POS7"});
    invoice.set({POSClerkID: "admin"});
    invoice.set({CustomerName: "Alice in Wonderland Tours"});
    invoice.set({IsFreightOverwrite: true});
    invoice.set({BillToCode: "CUST-000009"});
    InvoiceCollection.add( invoice );
    //var invoices = JSON.stringify({Invoices: InvoiceCollection.toJSON()});
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(cart){
        InvoiceDetailCollection.add( cart );
    });
    input.set({ "Invoices": InvoiceCollection.toJSON() });
    input.set({ "InvoiceDetails": InvoiceDetailCollection});
    alert( JSON.stringify(input.toJSON()) );
    input.save();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default Backbone sync handler maps CRUD to REST like the following:

- create → POST   /collection
- read → GET   /collection[/id]
- update → PUT   /collection/id
- delete → DELETE   /collection/id

Sometimes older servers emulate HTTP by mimicking the HTTP method with _method and X-HTTP-Method-Override header. If that is the case, you should set `Backbone.emulateHTTP` to true

If you want custom mappings, then you would need to override Backbone.sync. An example of overriding could be like the following:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options, error) {

  // Backwards compatibility with Backbone <= 0.3.3
  if (typeof options == 'function') {
    options = {
      success: options,
      error: error
    };
  }

  var resp = function(resp) {
    if (resp.status) {
      options.success(method != 'read' ? model : resp.data);
    }
    else {
      options.error('Record not found ' + resp.data);
    }
  };


  var store = model.customStorage || model.collection.customStorage;

  switch (method) {
    case 'read':    model.id ? store.read({id: model.id}, resp) : store.readAll(resp); break;
    case 'create':  store.create(model.attributes, resp); break;
    case 'update':  store.update(model.attributes, resp); break;
    case 'delete':  store.delete(model.id, resp); break;
  }
};
```

Where customStorage is your implementation, it could be anything you want that respects the methods I created. Some time ago, I created a backbone sync override for HTML5 WebSQL Storage, it is open sourced located on GitHub https://github.com/mohamedmansour/backbone.webStorage

I hope this helps you get started! Good Luck!

Comment: wait. where should i edit inorder to override the backbone.sync? and how should i call it on my view? Thank you

Comment: You are replacing `Backbone.sync`, notice the "Backbone.sync =", so you should place that after you include Backbone library.

Comment: sorry, but i would just like to clarify. since put is already enabled. Is it necessary for me to override the backbone.sync? if i want to use PUT can i use something like this? how would i call it?

Comment: Well, if only you need PUT, Backbone already provides PUT since the default sync handler maps CRUD to REST . so all you do is update the model.

Comment: So just call myModel.update it will execute a PUT by default on your server.

Comment: Aha, so if it doesn't accept POST, then your "create" wont work. You can override the default features to use PUT instead of POST, and etc.

Comment: Too bad the methodMap is private, if it was public, you would have easily switched the CRUD names. Search for "methodMap" in http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js, the function under it is Backbone.sync.

Comment: dude, i would just like to clarify again. **input.update();** is that how i call the sync and automatically it will do PUT? there is no update on the backbone docs.

Comment: @Dreyfus15 Backbone uses model.save to check if the model is a "new" or needs to be updated. If it is a new model, it will call "POST" method, while if it is updating the model, it will call the "PUT" method. Since your server doesn't like "POST", you would need to supply a custom backbone.sync and either intercept the "POST" method to be "PUT" or whatever you want.

Comment: hey, just would like to ask if i can pass a string to the server using backbone? i forgot that the server was expecting a jsonstring and all the convertion resides on the server side.